# How can I say raising/lowering a bike saddle?

Tags: vocabulary

I recently had a situation where I needed to ask someone if the height of the bike saddle was ok for them. How would you say this? Also, which verb would you use to express the idea of making it higher/lower?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are different ways to ask that. You can use "*einstellen*" or "*verstellen*" (to adjust) or also "*verändern*" (change):

> Soll ich den Sattel *höher* oder *tiefer* **einstellen**? Oder passt es so mit der Höhe?

> Soll ich den Sattel noch **verstellen**?

> Soll ich die Höhe des Sattels noch **verändern**?

Comment: runter- und hoch-stellen

Comment: Cute video about German bike vocabulary: https://youtu.be/rpT7dVgK9oQ?t=234

Comment: alternatively, "hoch/runter machen"

Comment: I'm not so sure about *tief*, maybe it's regional but I would say *niedrig* (or even *nieder*). *Tief* implies a negative height (below a reference level) for me.